# Do any technical standards / norms require software testing to be done?

Tags: development-process, standards

I am just thinking - ISO 9001, of course, say you need to have some quality control and quality assurance activities but it is up to you to define it and document it.

CMMI is not mandatory (it does tell you to do validation and verification to achieve Level 3).

But are there any norms/standards that actually prescribe to perform testing on software?
I believe this might be just the SIL for low-level SW controlling hardware in cars etc. But, to be honest, I do not know if ISO 61508, defining SIL, actually dictates the testing must be done - for SIL levels, it is under "recommended" or "highly recommended".

EDIT: The title edit was not correct, there are many standards for software testing itself.

Comment: Standards or norms?  Those are different things.  And are you looking for standards set by an international body, like ISO, or internal company standards, or . . .?  NASA, for example, has https://standards.nasa.gov/standard/nasa/nasa-std-87398, which requires validation and verification be done.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by having answer to this question?

Answer (score -1):

In Agile environments good practices are:

Test in the 4 agile testing quadrants - Unit, Integrated, UAT and Exploratory.

Test using the test pyramid - lots of unit tests that run fast on the bottom, just a few UI tests that run slow on the top.

Google or search here for more on those terms.

In software, few things are mandatory or dictated due to the very wide variety of languages, frameworks, etc. used for implementation and the constant and rapid speed at which they change and new ones appear.

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with the question.. these are practices, not technical standards prescribed activities that are mandatory

Comment: The question mentioned "norms".  Agile is the predominant development methodology that I see used across industries today.  These are norms for Agile testing.

Comment: and "to perform testing on software?" also suggests OP is seeking this sort of help.  I am trying to answer their main point not the fine details.